# A simple fixed-bandwidth 1D Gaussian KDE implementation for Python

Tags: python, kernel-density

I need a simple Kernel Density Estimation with fixed bandwidth and Gaussian kernel.

Alas, in `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` I saw only an automatic bandwidth selection. The `set_bandwidth` method, as far as I see, only multiplies the auto-selected values with some correcting ratios. And I just need to set the bandwidth I want to set.

I don't want to use my hand-written Python code for KDE: it works a bit too slow.

Don't you know any replacements of `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`?

Answer (score 1):

In [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html), you can supply a scalar to the `bw_method` option. This will set the `kde.factor` variable. `kde.factor` is a number by which the covariance matrix is multiplied, so it should be the same as the bandwidth.

Comment: So, I have to give it sqrt(sigma)?

Comment: You mean you want to know how the bandwidth is related to the standard deviation? They are not the same thing. You are probably looking for the formula that appears here under the section "Practical estimation of the bandwidth": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [KDE](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate.html#statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate) in statsmodels. Example [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/kernel_density.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the KDE's in scikit-learn (sklearn):
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html
It has a variety of different kernels you can try, and lets you directly set bandwidth, but apparently (!) has no methods for automatic bandwidth selection.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the [KernelSmoothing](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/user_manual/_generated/openturns.KernelSmoothing.html) class in OpenTURNS. An example is provided in [Non parametric distribution fitting](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/examples/data_analysis/estimate_non_parametric_distribution.html) and the theory is [described here](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/theory/data_analysis/kernel_smoothing.html). There is an automatic multidimensional bandwidth rule, but the bandwidth can be set by the user. Also, the library provides the Sheather and Jones "solve-the-equation" plugin rule which is efficient for multimodal distributions and a mixed rule (which is less CPU consuming than the former).